# Changing the length of an object

Tags: r

Alpha is an object of length 10, then

```
alpha <- alpha[2 * 1:5]
```

Makes it an object of length 5 consisting of just the former components with even index.
How is this working?
Also when running the code, the entire object contains only NA. Is there anyway of retaining the original values?
I added elements and still it showed NA.

Comment: You are subsetting alpha by the. 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, 10th values.  If the elements are not there, it would be NA

Comment: If you can update your post with the `dput` of alpha, it would be easier to understand what iss going on

Comment: *"just the components with even index"* and *"retaining the original values"* ... assign to a different variable instead of over-writing it?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a proper answer without knowing the content of `alpha` and what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but hope this helps.

Squared brackets are used for indexing:

```
alpha <- seq(10, 50, 10)

> alpha
[1] 10 20 30 40 50

> alpha[2]
[1] 20
```

If there's nothing in a position (e.g. if that position don't exist in the vector), it will return "Not Available" (NA):

```
> alpha[6]
[1] NA

> alpha[3:7]
[1] 30 40 50 NA NA
```

If you want to add new values to the vector, you specify the position(s) and attribute the value(s):

```
alpha[8:12] <- 8:12

> alpha
[1] 10 20 30 40 50 NA NA  8  9 10 11 12
# the positions with no values atributed are filled with NA
```

If you want to make an operation in only some positions, you specify the positions and make the operation over it:

```
> 2*alpha[4:8]
[1]  80 100  NA  NA  16
# positions 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 multiplied by 2
```

Which is different of using an operation to select positions:

```
> alpha[2*4:8]
[1]  8 10 12 NA NA
# showing the content of positions 8, 10, 12, 14 and 16
```